# Как лучше сделать 2 AppBar, один с информацией другой с поиском. Jetpack. Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Как лучше сделать два AppBar другой с поиском

```
Scaffold(topAppBar = {Column{AppBar() SearchBar()})
```

или лучше сделать

```
Scaffold(topAppBar = {Column{Row() Row()}) имеется ввиду свою реализацию
```

Можно вообще без Material создавать свое приложение

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. От материал вы не отвяжитесь - compose завязан на него (захардкоджены отступы хотя бы), в остальном бар делайте как удобно.